# Sending topic notifications using firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, backend

I need to implement broadcast notification through topics in fcm. I am using firebase-admin to send these. can anyone post the snippet of code to send these notifications through node.js?

Answer (score 2):

```
    const topic = "test";
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "New news",
        body: "2:45",
      },
    };
    admin
      .messaging()
      .sendToTopic(topic, payload)
      .then((response2) => {
        // Response2 is a message ID string.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response2);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

**First you need to subscribe the user to the given topic**

```
// These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
var registrationTokens = [
   'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1',
  // ...
   'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n'
];

// Subscribe the devices corresponding to the registration tokens to the
// topic.
admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic)
  .then(function(response) {
    // See the MessagingTopicManagementResponse reference documentation
    // for the contents of response.
    console.log('Successfully subscribed to topic:', response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
  });
```

**Then you can broadcast the notification using**

```
// The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/".
var topic = 'highScores';

var message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  topic: topic
};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging)

Comment: Have already gone through their documentation.I want to know where should we pass the server key in firebase admin. While intializing the app where should we pass the server key.

Comment: Oh ok I got it, its easy just to the Firebase console and then select your project and then its Project Settings then select Service Accounts tab, and copy the initializing code, and download the service account key by Generate private key

Comment: In the intialize app we have admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
})

Comment: What is this admin.credential.applicationDefault() . Should we need to pass the serverKey in the applicationDefault() function.

Comment: admin.credential.applicationDefault() returns a credential created from the Google Application Default Credentials that grants admin access to Firebase services. This credential can be used in the call to admin.initializeApp().

Google Application Default Credentials are available on any Google infrastructure, such as Google App Engine and Google Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0):

you will need
Firebase project
device registration tokens
firebase cloud function

working of firebase notification :
device to device notification :
from device 1 - firebase database(function triggers on writes to Database) -firebase cloud function (the cloud function will send notification to dev 2)- device2

Answer (score 0):

Be aware also of this "topic limitations" when sending topic messages:

Topic messaging supports unlimited subscriptions for each topic.

However, FCM enforces limits in these areas:

- One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics.
- If you are using batch import to subscribe app instances, each request is limited to 1000 app instances.

The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project.

If you send too many subscription requests in a short period of time, FCM servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota exceeded") response. Retry with exponential backoff.

Source: [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging).